# 3 Asteroids hit the planet - What happens next?

Tags: earth, explosions, asteroids

3 Large Asteroids, each the rough size of London, UK, in diameter. The Asteroids are rocky, with bits of water and ice in them as well.
They impact the Earth, at 57km/s, in South America, East Africa, and the Chinese Coast.

What effect(s) would this have on the Global Ecosystem, and the Earth itself?

Comment: Everyone dies. Plus, 57 km/s is more than the expected speed of an incoming solar asteroid, which strongly implies this is not a random disaster but a deliberate attack. So, should someone not die, other asteroids may be expected to follow.

Comment: Are three the size of the city of London or of the City of London, which are very different sizes? Three objects the size of the City rather than the city should be survivable.

Comment: If you search this site, you'll find that meteor-hits-planet questions have been asked before. What about those posts fails to answer your question? Also, VTC:NMF until you significantly limit the scope of your anticipated answer (the question is WAY too broad - do you really want to know about what happens to gnats?) and provide much better detail: meteor mass, size, and composition; impact angles; *specific* long/lat of impacts, timing and order of impacts, etc. This borders on asking us to write your story for you. Please be very specific with your question edits.

Comment: In another question, @AlexP provided a link to an impact estimator, which has been added to the Geology section of the [Worldbuilding Resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/143606/40609) page.

Answer (score 10):

Even one of these asteroids would cause a mass extinction. They're about 45km in diameter (London is big), far larger than the 10-15km object that caused the [K-Pg extinction event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cretaceous%E2%80%93Paleogene_extinction_event), and almost certainly coming in much faster.

Three of them simultaneously is clearly an attack, rather than a natural event, and one that will succeed: present-day humanity has no means of deflecting or destroying bodies of this size. It won't wipe out *all* life on earth, but it may well kill everything larger than [tardigrades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tardigrade), once the climate effects have set in.

Comment: Not necessarily an attack, as there are a number of triple asteroid systems out there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor-planet_moon#Triple_systems  (Though I admit one with 3 similarly-sized bodies seems unlikely.)  Also consider the way Shoemaker-Levy broke up, resulting in multiple Jupiter impacts: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_Shoemaker%E2%80%93Levy_9

Answer (score 3):

Someone has already done a lot of the work - https://www.purdue.edu/impactearth/Content/pdf/Documentation.pdf

Let's parse it out:

### Interpolating

Where are we on these charts? These charts assume an 18km asteroid on the top (solid-black) line. This is about 10 times the size of the next lower line. You're hypothetical is about 5x the top-line, so for the rest of this, I'm going to be imagining a line shifted up about half the distance between the solid and dashed line.

London is about 45km in diameter. Or, about 2.5 the 18km diameter rock. So, well take whatever the difference is from the 18km v. ~1.8km lines and multiply it by ${2.5} \over {10}$ or 0.25.

### Heat

If I'm reading the chart correctly, the edge of the 1.8km fireball is 400 kilometers. The edge of the 18km fireball is 2,000 kilometers (5x).

Interpolated, each 45km diameter strike will have a $2,000 km \times 5 \times 0.25$ = 2,500 km fireball.

For scale, the fireball will consume half of a continent the size of North America, South America, or Africa.

Everything flammable in this region (cloth, plant matter) will spontaneously combust under the intense heat.

[image]

### Earthquake

Each strike will be felt anywhere on the planet.

Each strike will also do moderate damage to all structures within roughly 6,000 km of the center (12,000 kilometer diameter). Combined, the three strikes will rattle nearly every structure on the planet with a magnitude 5 or greater earthquake.

[image]

### Blast

Steel framed structures out to 1,500 km will be knocked down by each strike's airburst blast.

Wooden frame structures out to 6,000 km from the center of the strike will be knocked down.

Probably safe to say all unsheltered life on each stricken continent is dead.

[image]

### Dust

450km for 1.8km, 4,500 km for 18 (10x). Fine dust will be scattered (4,500 x 10 x 0.25) = 11,250 kilometers radius.

Based on this : https://www.wired.com/2012/05/what-happens-to-all-that-volcanic-ash/ the ash settles at about 10 m/s. It should stay aloft for a few days (arbitrarily saying 14)

[image]

### Short-Term Environmental Effects

The dust clouds can become electrically charged, disrupting radio and satellite communication. Additionally, they shade the area beneath them from solar heating.

**How much shade?** Each strike creates an ash cloud 11,000 km in radius. The area of coverage is $\pi r^2$ or 380 million square kilometers. 1.14 billion square kilometers are shaded by all 3 strikes.

The [total surface area of the Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth) is only 510 million kilometers. So, the entire Earth will be shaded by ash and dust for at least two weeks.

**What will this do?** According to this [article](https://www.quora.com/How-long-can-different-plants-survive-without-sunlight-and-water?share=1) many species of plants can survive on root energy for months or years, but many other plant species can not survive 2 weeks without sunlight. Depending on seed availability, those plants may recover from a new generation of seeds, but the current living plants will probably perish.

### Mid-Term Environmental Effects

Based on the 3 strike zones you selected (S. America, Eastern Africa, Chinese coast), parts of Europe and most of North America will be spared the worst, and only will ride out 2 weeks of darkness.

Seedlings, powered by internal food reserves, will sprout in the worst-hit regions before the dust clears. Most food crops only require a few months to mature for harvest. In a few months time, plant life, other than forests, will have recovered.

People and animals that were in shelter (if that was possible) should be able to begin digging out in a few days.

Once the dust clears, satellites and the ground stations to command them should be available to assist in a regional effort to identify survivors and provide assist digging out from the rubble.

Without doing the math, I can't imagine a few weeks of darkness leading to an ice age. However, in the mid term, familiar weather patterns will be disrupted and unfamiliar.

The shock may have been enough to trigger one or more supervolcanoes into eruption. This would create a more persistent ash cloud that might lead to global cooling.

Shutting down for coronavrus shows that without mankind, nature will quickly spring back.

### Long Term Environmental Effects

Fission powerplants are very likely not equipped for this. We see at Chernobyl that ruptured plants are survivable, although the incidents of tumors and cancers increases. The new normal would be more frequent cancers.

The human population will be dropped down from 7 billion to the roughly 330 million in N. America, few million in Europe, and however many were fortunate enough to survive in the areas of devastation.

Comment: +1 for doing a great job with a poorly asked question. I'd give you another +1 if I could for finding a relevant scientific document to support your answer.  Well done!